# Jmeter :How to identify valid input for Concurrency Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I need to create 500 user /second for 30 minute. I have tried Jmeter "Thread Group". After completion of ramp up time. threads are still alive. Now I am tring to add "Concurrency Thread Group" to fix this issue but unable to identify appropriate  input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to proceed with the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) the relevant settings would be something like:

1. Add [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter Throughtput Shaping Timer]
2. Configure [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread) like:

   [image: JMeter Concurrency Thread Group]

This `${__tstFeedback(jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer,500,1000,10)}` means that Concurrency Thread Group is connected to the Throughput Shaping timer and will start from 500 to 1000 threads in order to reach and maintain 500 requests per second concurrency for the duration of 30 minutes. See [Schedule Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) chapter for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. It is working fine for me, I am able to complete my jmeter test within the predefined time. only one thing that is confusing me is, in summary report Samples showing 6,53,659. As 500 user/second for 1800 second. it should be 90,000. Please suggest If anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: It should be `900000`, try increasing upper threads limit and make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure). If you won't achieve the anticipated number of requests - it is either lack of resources on JMeter side so you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) or it is the bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I can able to generate 885756 users. the link you have provided is very useful for memory optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thread Group's Duration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

> Thread Group also provides a scheduler. Click the checkbox at the bottom of the Thread Group panel to enable/disable extra fields in which you can enter the duration of test

Just enter 1800 second (60 * 30 minutes) and test will stop after 30 minutes.